# Android O how to disable opening apps from smart text selection

Tags: webview, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app with editable webview. In Android O (8) Google added new feature Smart Text Selection:
https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#sh
I want to disable opening hyperlinks, google maps, dialler from smart text selection like:
[image]
I tried to add

```
<head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
</head>
```

but it doesn't work (smart selection menu item still appears). I need to disable only opening this 3 apps from webview content.
Do you now how to disable this new feature?
Thank you in advance.